# Is there any way with one of the Java logging frameworks to restrict log records from being logged unless some security feature is disabled?

Tags: java, security, logging

Is there any way with one of the Java logging frameworks to restrict log records from being logged unless some security feature is disabled?

Use case:

- Company X has Java software called `SuperThing` in package `com.x.superthing`
- Java class `com.x.superthing.SuperSecretThingy` contains lots of important IP
- Company X wants to be able to enable logging from `SuperSecretThingy` using one of the standard Java logging frameworks (java.util.logging, log4j, logback, etc.); if they have to do something special to make this work, that's ok.
- When someone outside Company X wants to run `SuperThing`, they should not be able to enable logging from `SuperSecretThingy`, e.g. with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=...` because some of the log messages contain sensitive information

---

**Constraint:** code in the class in question (`SuperSecretThingy`) must not have a compile-time dependency on anything special, so that the logging code is just the normal stuff.

```
class SuperSecretThingy
{
   final static private Logger logger = 
       LoggerFactory.getLogger(SuperSecretThingy.class);
   // this example uses SLF4J

   ...

   public void foo()
   {
      logger.info("Entering foo");
      do_stuff();
      logger.info("Exiting foo");
   }
}
```

---

There's [a `Filter` feature in log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/architecture.html#Filter):

> In addition to the automatic log Level filtering that takes place as described in the previous section, Log4j provides Filters that can be applied before control is passed to any LoggerConfig, after control is passed to a LoggerConfig but before calling any Appenders, after control is passed to a LoggerConfig but before calling a specific Appender, and on each Appender.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? If so, then I can filter out log events from a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make your own logger class that wraps the log methods so you test for whatever your condition is and then call the logger if the condition is what you want.

Something like:

```
class SuperSecretThingy {
   final static private SecretLogger logger = 
       SecretLogger.getLogger(SuperSecretThingy.class);

   public void foo(){
      logger.debug("Entering foo");
      do_stuff();
      logger.debug("Exiting foo");
   }
...
}
class SecretLogger {
  private Log log;
  public SecretLogger(Class c) {
    log = LogFactory.getLog(c);
  }
  public void debug(String message) {
    if (mySecretConditions()) {
      log.debug(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment on your question, but it sounds like [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customconfig.html) is what you want.